# Angular 2 material design for email validation

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi I am trying to implement form validation using material design with Angular 2.
Here is the input field :

```
<md-input-container class="example-full-width" 
          dividerColor="{{username.untouched || username.valid?'primary':'warn'}}">
          <input mdInput placeholder="Email" type="email" name="username" id="username"
            #username="ngModel" required 
            [(ngModel)]="loginModel.username">
        </md-input-container>
```

I the above code, I am trying to put red color bottom border if:

1. Field is touched and `required` filed condition is not met
2. Field is touched and there is invalid email string

The first condition is being fulfilled using `username.untouched || username.valid?'primary':'warn'` but unable to validate email.
Any suggestion.

Edit : I tried using `<md-hint>` as:

```
<md-hint *ngIf="username.errors &&(username.dirty || username.touched)">
              <span [hidden]="username.errors?.required || !username.errors?.email">Invalid email</span>
              <span [hidden]="!username.errors?.required">Required.</span>
            </md-hint>
```

It is working fine for Required but not for incorrect email.

Comment: Email validator was added only since angular v4.0.0-beta.6 and it requires `email` attribute. See also example https://plnkr.co/edit/dFoPGKTQ9xPsQK19DjYg?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui it is showing Property 'email' does not exist on type 'typeof Validators'. Any suggestion?

Comment: As you can see in my plunker i created it manually

Comment: @yurzui it would be very helpful to understand if you put some comments on plunkr

Answer (score 6):

Use `<md-error>`, and you don't have to worry about error validation styles.

HTML:

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="email" [formControl]="emailFormControl" required>
    <md-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
    This field is required
    </md-error>
    <md-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('pattern')">
    Please enter a valid email address
    </md-error>
</md-input-container>
```

TS:

```
import { FormControl, Validators, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

const EMAIL_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
export class FormlayoutComponent {
    private emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(EMAIL_REGEX)]);
....
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So there is no existing email validator in MD?

Comment: @Davor, in your component file from the Github:


const EMAIL_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;

emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(EMAIL_REGEX)]);

}


https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/a2a25bead0da81e17a2853fa60426e0deed10f62/src/material-examples/input-errors/input-errors-example.ts